# how to get value from different zones using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass unique passnum value to different zone information  using jquery, so that the passnum  information is specific to a specific zone.
for example zone1 may passnum = 100 and zone2  may have 50

Is it possible to pass the unique passnum value to each of the zones`<h5> </h5>`based on the zone using jquery? since there could be hundreds of zone blocks dynamically created.

```
<div class="wrapper" class="zone1">

other divs here (could have unknown amount of div block or tages here


<div ><span class="pass-num"><h5>some num  </h5></span> </div>

</div>



<div class="wrapper" class="zone2">

other divs here (could have unknown amount of div block or tages here


<div><span class="pass-num"><h5>some num(pass val here)  </h5></span> </div>

</div>

I have cthe ode below which works when u know the zone and structure

$(document).ready(function() {

            var passnum ="110";
            var passtext="All";


            $('div.pass-text>h4').text(passtext);
            $('div.pass-num>h4').text(passnum);





    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Just to say that Id must be unique on single page.

Comment: This selector `$('div.pass-num>h4')` trying to select `div` with `pass-num` class and find `h4` in children. Maybe you trying to write this: `$('span.pass-num>h5')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your html, this function should do it:

```
function get_passnum(zone) {
   return $('.zone'+zone+' .pass-num').text();
}
```

Use it like:

```
passnum = get_passnum(2);
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/rUYdk/)